# VBA for max of array returns a value of 0

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, max

I'm trying to write a macro that returns the maximum value of a column based on the value in the other column. I thought my code was working but it just returns a value of zero. I'm trying to do this for a table of around 2500 lines. I created a smaller table to try to figure out what the problem was but I just get the same result (It returns 0 instead of 10).

Here's my code:

```
Sub test()

    imax = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Dim MaxArray(2 To 11) As String

    For t = 2 To 11

        If (Cells(t, 1) = 1) Then MaxArray(t) = Cells(t, 2).Value

    Next t

    Cells(2, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.max(MaxArray)

End Sub
```

Here's the result I get:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Max of Column 1

    1           4              0
    1           6
    1           3
    1           10
    1           9
    2           5
    2           2
    2           3
    2           8
```

Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

Some notes: I know how to do this using a pivot table or a formula in excel but I really want it to go in a macro that runs a bunch of other stuff before and after it. I just want to push the button once instead of stopping and having to add a table or formula and then push another button to continue.

Comment: Did you try changing `Dim MaxArray(2 To 11) As String` to `Dim MaxArray(2 To 11) As Integer`. Not sure but maybe this is the issue

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Cells(2, 3).Value = Evaluate("=MAX(B2:B11))")
```

Maybe also changing the array type to number `Double`, `Integer` might help.

And btw I think this will also work to reduce your loop:

```
Set MaxArray = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(11,2))
```

Comment: Thank you both! The integer call out was the problem. As for the set function to reduce the loop, I think I must not be using it right because I get a compile error that says "can't assign to array".

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark as answer. As for the array maybe the range is set incorrectly too wide or too narrow

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the integer suggestion but then I realized that my actual numbers are rounded to two or three decimal places. I tried to fix that by using Long instead of Integer but it still just returns an integer. How do I get it to include the decimal places?

code:

```
Sub test2()

imax = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim MaxArray(2 To 11) As Long

For t = 2 To 11  

    If (Cells(t, 1) = 1) Then MaxArray(t) = Cells(t, 2).Value

Next t

Cells(2, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.max(MaxArray)

End Sub
```

data table:

Column 1    Column 2       Max of 1's

```
1         4.66      10
1         6.2
1         3.987
1         10.125
1         9.1
2         5.3
2         2.21
2         3.654
2         8.12
2         20.56
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Never mind. I just saw the "double" part of the comment. Using double works.